# symfony: autowire has null function without being null

Tags: symfony

i've tried to make controllers for my symfony API, however using the autowire feature of symfony keeps returning nullthe code returns null when i use the function $trustedUser->getName()

the code returns null when i use the function: $trustedUser->getName()
In the Controller at getTrustedUserByID()

```
    $this->logger->info($trustedUser->getName()." ".$trustedUser->getId());
    return new JsonResponse([
        "name" => $trustedUser->getName(),
    ]);
```

my controller looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\Status;
use App\Entity\TrustedUser;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;


class TrustedUserController extends AbstractController
{
    private $logger;

    public function __construct(LoggerInterface $logger)
    {
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }
    /**
     * @Route("/trustedUser/{id}", name="getTrustedUserByID", methods={"GET","HEAD"})
     */
    public function getTrustedUserByID(TrustedUser $trustedUser,$id)
    {
        if (!$trustedUser) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException(
                'No trustedUsers found for id '.$id
            );
        }
        $this->logger->info($trustedUser->getName()." ".$trustedUser->getId());
        return new JsonResponse([
            "name" => $trustedUser->getName(),
        ]);
    }
}
```

My entity like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\TrustedUserRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=TrustedUserRepository::class)
 */
class TrustedUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $civilite;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $lastname;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $phone;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $mail;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity=Status::class, inversedBy="trustedUser", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
     */
    private $id_status;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getCivilite(): ?string
    {
        return $this->civilite;
    }

    public function setCivilite(string $civilite): self
    {
        $this->civilite = $civilite;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getLastname(): ?string
    {
        return $this->lastname;
    }

    public function setLastname(string $lastname): self
    {
        $this->lastname = $lastname;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPhone(): ?int
    {
        return $this->phone;
    }

    public function setPhone(int $phone): self
    {
        $this->phone = $phone;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getMail(): ?string
    {
        return $this->mail;
    }

    public function setMail(string $mail): self
    {
        $this->mail = $mail;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getIdStatus(): ?Status
    {
        return $this->id_status;
    }

    public function setIdStatus(Status $id_status): self
    {
        $this->id_status = $id_status;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

And my repository looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Repository;

use App\Entity\TrustedUser;
use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Repository\ServiceEntityRepository;
use Doctrine\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;

/**
 * @method TrustedUser|null find($id, $lockMode = null, $lockVersion = null)
 * @method TrustedUser|null findOneBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null)
 * @method TrustedUser[]    findAll()
 * @method TrustedUser[]    findBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null, $limit = null, $offset = null)
 */
class TrustedUserRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository
{
    public function __construct(ManagerRegistry $registry)
    {
        parent::__construct($registry, TrustedUser::class);
    }

    // /**
    //  * @return TrustedUser[] Returns an array of TrustedUser objects
    //  */
    /*
    public function findByExampleField($value)
    {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('t')
            ->andWhere('t.exampleField = :val')
            ->setParameter('val', $value)
            ->orderBy('t.id', 'ASC')
            ->setMaxResults(10)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult()
        ;
    }
    */

    /*
    public function findOneBySomeField($value): ?TrustedUser
    {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('t')
            ->andWhere('t.exampleField = :val')
            ->setParameter('val', $value)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getOneOrNullResult()
        ;
    }
    */
}
```

Both the entity and repository were generated using the make:entity

[And the database looks like this](https://i.gyazo.com/c0048becf62a37b98cf16c20e166bdd7.png)
[The results looks like this](https://i.gyazo.com/240b7ce2e516f764e2a54676ee235a05.png)

Comment: Please clarify what 'keeps returning null' means.  Is $trustedUser being set to null?  Seems unlikely as that would generate a different error message.

Comment: Sorry!
Issue is that all functions i get with $trustedUser returns null like $trustedUser->getName() as shown on this screenshot
https://i.gyazo.com/240b7ce2e516f764e2a54676ee235a05.png
I have no idea what causes this

Comment: Please share more details by editing your question - where **exactly** does the code return null, and how should that be related to autowiring?

Comment: I edited the question to show exactly where the code returns null

Comment: Is this your code or a legacy project you inherited?  I can't think of a way that $trustedUser would be injected without it's properties being set.  Have you double checked that the name column in your database table has an actual value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does not look like an autowiring issue to me - Doctrine entities are not autowired, but loaded through a `ParamConverter`. This enables injecting an entity to a controller method through providing the ID of that entity.

To get this working, you need to install the package `sensio/framework-extra-bundle`. This package contains the converter.

Additionally, if you don't need the raw ID in your controller, there's no need to inject it. The package's converter will throw an exception on its own if the entity is not found

Comment: I installed the package and it worked!
I now receive the correct data!
Thank you so much!
As to why i use $id is because for some reason in the new version [it returns me an error if i try to use $id directly](https://i.gyazo.com/387c04d1e05fd38de6c72c46f22e37ff.png)

Comment: Yeah, but through that ParamConverter, the controller method isn't called after all if the entitiy could not be loaded

Comment: So is there anyway to fix that error to use $id directly?

Comment: Which error are you talking about? Using the given code, there is **no** situation where `!$trustedUser` could evaluate to `true`, as this is **always** an instance of `TrustedUser`

Comment: i'm talking about 
Undefined variable '$id'.
when i try to remove the definition of id in getTrustedUserByID(TrustedUser $trustedUser,$id) [shown here](https://i.gyazo.com/387c04d1e05fd38de6c72c46f22e37ff.png)

Comment: Just remove that code, it is completely useless :)